# Classes of transcendental numbers?

Tags: transcendental-numbers, algebraic-numbers

Let $\mathbb{A}_1$ be the set of algebraic numbers. The usual definitions of this set is the roots of all non-trivial polynomials with integer coefficients.

The set of transcendental numbers is defined as the non-algebraic reals. However it seems reasonable to define the set $\mathbb{A}_n$ as the set of solutions of all non-trivial polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{A}_{n-1}$.

Is this something looked into? If yes is the set $\mathbb{A}_\infty$ equal to $\mathbb{R}$? In which $\mathbb{A}_n$ are the famous transcendental numbers as $\pi$, $\phi$ and e?

(I am not sure about the tags I should use. So feel free to change them.)

Comment: It seems to me that $\mathbb{A}_{\infty}$ is a countable union of countably many sets, hence it is countable. In particular, it cannot be equal to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Ah, yes, very true!

Comment: Set of algebraic numbers (to clarify, over $\mathbb{Q}$, as a subset of $\mathbb{C}$) is *algebraically closed*. That is, $\mathbb{A}_2=\mathbb{A}_1$.

Comment: Yes, indeed....

Comment: But there are other "sieves", but they rely on computational models, theories, formal logic etc. I do not understand those things very well, just know that there are. Numbers computable, describable etc. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any root of a polynomial equation with algebraic coefficients is still algebraic. In other words, the field of algebraic numbers is algebraically closed. Therefore, $\mathbb{A}_1=\mathbb{A}_2=\mathbb{A}_3=\cdots$

Comment: Oh, right! My question is stupid.

Comment: @tst No, it isn't. (Unless one is a professional mathematician specialising in algebra, then it's one of the fundamental things one ought to be aware of.) It's a natural and interesting question, which happens to have a simple answer.